# Reading content from a file and storing it to String in C

Tags: c, http, web

I've written a simple http server in C and am now trying to implement HTML files.
For this I need send a response, containing the content of the HTML file.
How do I do that best?
Do I read the file line by line, and if so how do I store them in a single string?
Thanks already!

Comment: fread allows you to specify where in the buffer to start and returns the number of characters read.  So you can just do that in a look until fread returns 0.

Comment: No and no and no. Perhaps you'd even use the `sendfile` system call

Comment: @Antii Haapala What do you mean by no no no?

Comment: "Do I read the file line by line," --> use a loop with `fgets()`

Comment: There is no real difference between reading a file from a socket with recv and reading a file from the disk with fread.  You still need a loop that reads bytes and appends them to the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of reading a text file by chunks which, if the file is big, would be faster than reading the file line by line.

As @tadman said in his comment, text files aren't generally big so reading them in chunks doesn't make any real difference in speed but web servers serve other files too - like perhaps photos or movies (which are big).  So if you are only going to read text files then reading line by line might be simpler (you could use fgets instead of fread) but if you are going to read other kinds of files then reading all of them in chunks means you can do it the same way for all of them.

However, as @chux said in his comment, there is another difference between reading text files and binary files.  The difference is that text files are opened in text mode: `fopen(filename,"r");`  and binary files must be opened in binary mode: `fopen(filename,"rb");`  A web server could probably open all files in binary mode because web browsers ignore whitespace anyway but other kinds of programs need to know what the line endings will be so it can make a difference.

https://onlinegdb.com/HkM---r2X

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // we will make the buffer 200 bytes in size
    // this is big enough for the whole file
    // in reality you would probably stat the file
    // to find it's size and then malloc the memory
    // or you could read the file twice:
    // - first time counting the bytes
    // - second time reading the bytes
    char buffer[200]="", *current=buffer;
    // we will read 20 bytes at a time to show that the loop works
    // in reality you would pick something approaching the page size
    // perhaps 4096?  Benchmarking might help choose a good size
    int bytes, chunk=20, size=sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(char);
    // open the text file in text mode
    // if it was a binary file you would need "rb" instead of "r"
    FILE *file=fopen("test.html","r");
    if(file)
    {
        // loop through reading the bytes
        do {
            bytes=fread(current,sizeof(char),chunk,file);
            current+=bytes;
        } while (bytes==chunk);
        // close the file
        fclose(file);
        // terminate the buffer so that string function will work
        *current='\0';
        // print the buffer
        printf("%s",buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Faster" is kind of subjective here since reading a file in C is going to be pretty fast no matter how you slice it. This could be made even faster by skipping C file IO and using the kernel `sendfile` feature if available.

Comment: @tadman Sure, but C is cross platform and he may use a unix that is not linux or even use windows (or an embedded system with no OS like I do) so I kept the answer generic.  In the case of small html files you are right that there is no real "faster" but in general there is - his http server might be serving multi terabyte video files as well so I gave him something that would work for binary and text files regardless of size.  I did not go into details about allocating the memory or testing for errors because that wouldobfuscate the point I was trying to make.

Comment: "so I gave him something that would work for binary and text files regardless of size" --> best to remark that for binary files to open the file in binary mode `"rb"`.